# Vertx : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACHAT

Tags: java, hsqldb, vert.x

Good morning, 
I want to connect my vertx app with Sql database by using odbc, but when I run my code a weird error appears :  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACHAT

I tried to delete ?shutdown but it stills the same error

Here is my code :

```
 public void start(Future<Void> startFuture){
    String file="/Test1";
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
       router.route(file).handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.setChunked(true);            
        JsonObject config = new JsonObject()
                  .put("url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:odbcName?shutdown=true")   
                  .put("user", "sa")
                  .put("password", "****")
                  .put("driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
                  .put("max_pool_size", 30);
        JDBCClient client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, config);

        client.getConnection(res -> {
                  if (res.succeeded()) {
                    SQLConnection connection = res.result();
                    connection.query("select id from dbo.achat", res2 -> {
                      if (res2.succeeded()) {
                          System.out.println("oki");
                      }
                      else { System.out.println(res2.cause().toString()); }
                    });
                  } else {
                    System.out.println("Cnx failed !!");
                  }
                });
        routingContext.vertx().setTimer(8000, tid ->  routingContext.response().end());
    });
```

And for my server :

```
     vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router::accept)
            .listen(8085, "localhost", res -> {                    
                if (res.succeeded()){
                    startFuture.complete();    
                }
                else
                    startFuture.fail(res.cause());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection to HSQLDB from Java apps is via JDBC, not ODBC. Your connection settings use JDBC.

The line below creates a connection to an in-memory database, which is empty when you start:

```
 put("url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:odbcName?shutdown=true")
```

The schema `DBO` and table `ACHAT`must be created before you can access it.

Comment: Thank you fred for your reply, but it stills little bit unclear, using only my database name shouldn't resolve my problem. And for my Achat table I suppose that Vertx can read it from connection. ( I already created it in my sql database).
Regards.

Comment: Find out the real database name and connection type and use this information for getting a connection.

Comment: It gives me error when I change configuration to : 

.put("url", "jdbc:hsqldb:url://localhost;onp;user=sa;password=sa;")

2016-04-12T13:14:22.391+0100  SEVERE  could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@91823327[file =null, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: setPath reason: java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte